# Cannot connect to pluggable database in Oracle XE Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle21c, pluggable-database

I have recently installed Oracle database 21c(XE) in my local and it was working fine. Since this morning, even though I can connect to XE database user, I cannot connect to the user in XEPDB1.It throws following error when connect through sqldeveloper. Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12526, TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are in restricted mode
```

My tnsnames.org as follows.

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my ip add)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )


LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my ip add)(PORT = 1521))

XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my ip add)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = XEPDB1)
    )
  )
  
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

And my listener.ora

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\ME\product\21c\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\ME\product\21c\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my ip add)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. Followed this post. https://www.dbaplus.ca/2020/10/pluggable-database-opened-with.html